# How to use {Switch, Route} in hierarchical components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, components, react-component

I have routes in App.js mainly Logout, Signin and Home.
Inside App.js :

```
return(
<>
<Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Home} /> 
      <Route exact path='/signin' component={Signin} />
      <Route exact path='/logout' component={Logout} />
</Switch>
</>)
```

Also, I want Routes inside Home.js :

```
return( 
<>
<Navbar/>
<Switch>
      <Route exact path='/'>
        <LandingPage />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path='/settings'>
        <Settings username={username} />
      </Route>
</Switch>
</>
)
```

The LandingPage component is default for Home page, and Navbar is common in both LandingPage and Settings.
LandingPage component is showing perfectly but when I click "settings" button from Navbar, the Settings component is not showing. Other Routes are working fine. 
Inside Navbar I used NavLink:

```
<NavLink className="nav-link" to="/">
      HOME
</NavLink>
<NavLink className="nav-link" to="/settings">
      SETTINGS
</NavLink>
```

Why the Settings Component is not showing ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
```

Because of the `exact` flag, anything that isn't precisely `"/"` will not match this. So when the url becomes `"/settings"`, you stop rendering your Home component, which in turn means there's nothing trying to render a route at "/settings"

The likely fix is to remove the exact, and also rearrange your components so this case comes after the sign in/sign out cases:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path='/signin' component={Signin} />
  <Route exact path='/logout' component={Logout} />
  <Route path='/' component={Home} /> 
</Switch>
```